# Command Yarn build for Build with Vite.js and React.js doesn’t working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, vite

Recently I’m trying using Vite in my React applications.

But after I run the command **yarn build** has created a Build folder but the application doesn’t work, when I open the index.html show up only a blank page.

When I run **yarn start** I can see my application running perfectly but when I try to build it doesn’t work!

Someone has any ideia what’s happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution; in **vite.config.ts** need just add “**base: './'**“ when you are exporting the configs, example below:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react ()],
base: './', ⬅️
})
```

I hope this help some one else! ;)